# Flutter widget test find text failing after 3.10 update

Tags: flutter, testing

I have a Flutter widget test that started failing only after I updated to 3.10. The widget in question has a key `Key('time')` and has a text widget that should be showing "11:23 AM". By test case follows.

```dart
await tester.pumpWidget(page);
await tester.pumpAndSettle();
expect(find.byKey(Key('time')), findsOneWidget);
print((find.byKey(Key('time')).first.evaluate().single.widget as Text).data);
expect(find.text('11:23 AM'), findsOneWidget);
```

Only the last line fails. The widget with the correct key can be found and its data is "11:23 AM". Only finding that text fails, even when I find offstage widgets and rich text. The widget tree shows that the widget exists.

```
└SizedBox(width: 65.0, renderObject: RenderConstrainedBox#ea972 relayoutBoundary=up18)
 └Text-[<'time'>]("11:23 AM", textAlign: right, dependencies: [DefaultSelectionStyle, DefaultTextStyle, MediaQuery])
  └RichText(textAlign: right, softWrap: wrapping at box width, maxLines: unlimited, text: "11:23 AM", dependencies: [Directionality, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#16937]], renderObject: RenderParagraph#b21b5 relayoutBoundary=up19)
```

Again, this test only started failing after updating Flutter from 3.7 to 3.10. What might be happening?